# Namespace error in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="Liz.MainPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Liz"
xmlns:common="using:Liz.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TempA">
        <Border Background="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TempB">
        <Border Background="Blue">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <common:TemplateSelector x:Key="itemsTemplateSelector"
                         TemplateA="{StaticResource TempA}"
                         TemplateB="{StaticResource TempB}" />
```

I'm trying to utilize a data template selector, but in my xmal, I keep getting an error in this line of code:

Error   1   The name "TemplateSelector" does not exist in the namespace "using:Liz.Common".

and my TemplateSelector class is defined in my Common namespace as follows:

```
namespace Liz.Common
{
public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    int count = 0;
    public DataTemplate TemplateA { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TemplateB { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore
        (object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
            count++;
            return TemplateA;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            return TemplateB;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas as to why I keep getting this error?  I have even tried defining the TemplateSelector in the local (Liz) namespace, with the same results.
Note: The intellisence dropdown finds the TemplateSelector name just fine when using common:, but I still get the error after selecting it from intellisence.

Comment: What is the name of the assembly in which `TemplateSelector` is defined?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little please? I'm still fairly new to C# development...

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the above XAML. I created a new project, added the class and inserted the XAML snippet. The XAML editor reported the same error at first, but the build succeeded and the error disappeared after that.

[Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10676122/Liz.zip)'s the resulting project for you to check.